# How to make swf mobile friendly

Tags: html, flash, mobile

How to create swf content mobile friendly ? 
you don't need flash player installed to open content .
like `http://issuu.com`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem as i wanted to run swf in iOS device. 
I achieved the solution by converting that swf in html5.

How i did this?

```
1> save your fla as html5 canvas
2> now your unsupported code of as3 will be commented while converting
3> rewrite your as3 code in javascript for the same
4> publish 
5> you will get .html and .js now you can use it in any device which has html5 supported browser
```

Comment: +1 Thanks , Btw,are you have inspect element for that sites ? they still use .swf files .
I want to know what they used

Comment: sorry dear, i have no idea about how they have used, well i have to explore more onto this.

Comment: Some sites use https://ruffle.rs/#usage to emulate Flash. You can check it out.